# Show all commits with diff for a file

Tags: git

I'm looking for a cleaner way to accomplish the following:

```
for a in $(git log --abbrev=commit --pretty=format:'%H' -- '**/MyFile.java'); do git show $a -- '**/MyFile.java'; done
```

I want to `git show` all changes to a file for all commits that have made changes to this file.

Comment: Are you familiar with [`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame)? This will show the commits for the most recent changes in a file, line by line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this help you ?

```
git log -p **/MyFile.java
```

Comment: `**/MyFile.java` must be quoted